# How to run oracle PL/SQL in C++?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to run SQL script from a C++ program. 
My code goes like this:

```c++
int main()
{
     //.....
     sql_stmt = "Insert into t1 values ('qwerty');\nInsert into t1 values ('dothar');";
     sql_stmt = "DECLARE\nrollback_check_counter number;\n"
    "BEGIN\n"
    "rollback_check_counter :=1;\n"
    "SAVEPOINT sp_1;\nIF rollback_check_counter = 1 THEN\n"
    "BEGIN\n"+sql_stmt+"EXCEPTION\n"
    "WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN\n"
    "rollback_check_counter :=0;\n"
    "ROLLBACK TO sp_1\n"
    "WHEN OTHERS THEN\n"
    "rollback_check_counter :=0;\n"
    "ROLLBACK TO sp_1\n"
    "END;\n"
    "END IF;\n"
    "commit;\n"
    "END;";


    try 
    {
        Connection *conn = env->createConnection(user,passwd); //error prone
        Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement();
        stmt->setSQL(sql_stmt);
        row_count = stmt->execute(); //stmt->execute(sql_stmt);

        Connection::conn->terminateStatement(Statement *stmt);
        //con->terminateStatement(stmt);
        env->terminateConnection(conn);
        Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
    }
    catch(SQLException& ex)
    {}
//.....
return 0;
}
```

When I run the insert statement only, it runs well. But when I form an SQL script structure it seems to fail. I want to do so because I want to implement rollback. What am I missing? Could anyone suggest any alternative to implement it?

Comment: I don't know C++ but in JDBC you cannot send more than one statement using the `execute()` function. I assume this is a restriction imposed by the Oracle protocol and therefor I would guess it's not possible in C++ either. You will need to split your script and run each statement individually and do the transaction handling in the C++ code

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you suggest me any alternative other than creating individual statement for each record and executing them one by one. I intend to run 300 INSERT sql statement simultaneously. 
Or any way of rollback if possible ?

Comment: Instead of executing sql code, write a stored procedure in the Oracle database, and execute it from C++, so you still have transaction support.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure.
Use [Pro*C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro*C) which can be used for embedded sql programming.
For documentation refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/toc.htm)
Basic tutorials [here](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/pro-c-tutorial)